# Is flattening a natural isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, natural-transformations

Consider the following categories:

1. $≔\operatorname{FinVec}_ℝ$ of finite dimensional real vector spaces, whose morphisms are the linear maps
2. $ℍ≔\operatorname{FinHilb}_ℝ$ the category of finite dimensional real Hilbert spaces, with $\hom(ℍ)$ being the linear isometries.
3. (optional) $≔$ The category of finite dimensional real Hilbert spaces which are constructible as a finite combination of direct sums $⊕$, tensor products $⊗$ and dual operations $*$ from $ℝ$, with the morphisms being the linear isometries.

Consider a family $η$ of (isometric) isomorphisms $η_V：V → ℝ^{\dim(V)}$, that map a vector to its flattened representation. For example, if $V=ℝ^n⊗ℝ^m$, then we can consider the classical [vectorization mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)).

**Question:** Is there, for $ ∈ \{, ℍ, \}$, such a family $η$ that is a [natural isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation)? (in the sense that $η$ is a natural isomorphism from the identity functor $\operatorname{id}_$ to some other functor $G：→$)

---

**My thoughts:** First, I am not sure whether $ℍ$ and $$ can be identified as the same here. We know that all Hilbert spaces are isometrically isomorphic to $ℓ^2(B)$. However, it doesn't seem clear to me whether all Hilbert spaces of the same dimension are somehow *naturally* isomorphic, which of course this very question is a partial to.

Secondly, we need to construct a functor $G：→$ such that $G(f)∈\hom_(ℝ^{\dim(V)}, ℝ^{\dim(W)})$ if $f∈\hom_(V, W)$. I really am not sure what to do here without taking a basis. Of course once we take some basis $B=\{b_1, …, b_{\dim(V)}\}$ in $V$, we can simply map the basis elements to some $e_1, …, e_{\dim(V)}$ in $ℝ^{\dim(V)}$. But it seems essentially impossible to construct $G$ without referencing a basis. So how can we prove such a functor does not exist?

In the case of $$, assuming all spaces are equipped with the standard induced inner product and standard basis, we can even give a complete description of the family $η$, by choosing a consistent ordering: given $U⊕V$, map $∑_{i} α_i |(u_i,0)⟩ + ∑_j β_j |(0, v_j)⟩$ to $∑_i α_i |e_i⟩ + ∑_j β_j |e_{\dim(U)+j}⟩$, and for $U⊗V$ map $∑_{ij} α_{ij} |u_i⊗ v_j⟩$ to $∑_{k=1}^{\dim(U)⋅\dim(V)} α_{k//\dim(U), k \% \dim(U)} |e_k⟩$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, assuming the axiom of global choice. Let $\mathbb{W}$ be the full subcategory of $\mathbb{V}$ consisting only of the objects $\{\mathbb{R}^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. The inclusion functor $\mathbb{W} \to \mathbb{V}$ is fully faithful and essentially surjective. Therefore, it gives rise to an equivalence of categories, which produces the natural isomorphism $\eta$ you seek.

The analogous fact holds for $\mathbb{U}$ and $\mathbb{H}$, since all finite-dimensional real Hilbert spaces are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$ as Hilbert spaces.

Without choice, I expect this to be impossible.

Edit: indeed, it is impossible. In fact, this principle (for either general real vector spaces or for real Hilbert spaces) implies that for all families $\{S_i \mid i \in I\}$ of finite, non-empty sets, $\prod\limits_{i \in I} S_i$ is non-empty. This fact cannot be proved without choice.

Since we can’t make flattening natural without choice, you should not look for any sort of explicit description of the flattening functor.

Comment: Thank, that already made things a bit clearer to me. But I am unsure what to make of the functor having no explicit description. Does it mean we do not know how the flattening transformation look like? But it is usually considered such a simple transformation?!

Comment: And secondly a thing that itches me is that flattening is non-injective in the sense that many different spaces get mapped to the same ℝⁿ, whereas e.g. the double dual functor is injective on objects. Is it correct that this property is called *isocofibration*? It seems that this gives rise to another level of "niceness" for vector space isomorphisms?

Comment: @Hyperplane More precisely, there are many, many ways to pick a flattening functor that does the job. So we can’t say much about what any one way looks like (at least not without some strong and unusual set-theoretic axioms like $V = HOD$). Flattening is not considered a simple operation; typically, it’s not really considered an operation at all. I’m not really sure what an icosofibration is; I haven’t heard that term before. You say many different spaces map to the same $\mathbb{R}^n$, but that’s only true in a sense; these spaces are isomorphic to each other after all.

Comment: They are isomorphic, but what it means from a practical standpoint (and I am coming to this from an applied lens), flattening *"destroys metadata"*, because e.g. if you flatten an image represented by a matrix, you can no longer discern the original width and height from the flattened representation. the same is not true if you merely transpose the image, or unsqueeze a dimension (i.e. $ℝⁿ⊗ℝᵐ→ℝⁿ⊗ℝᵐ⊗ℝ¹$), these universal transformations in some sense preserve the metadata of the shape information and I had been wondering if this notion somehow could be made precise using CT.

Comment: Hence my gut feeling was that flatterning somehow should be unnatural, but as it turns out now this was the wrong notion and it seems what I was looking for is (possibly?) this  [isocofibration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/injective-on-objects+functor) property, which I first saw here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/479790/99220. (please note I am a complete novice w.r.t. CT. If you have a book recommendation that particularly focuses on $\operatorname{FinVec}_ℝ$ (or ℂ) that would be appreciated a lot)